# what is occupying linux low memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, low-memory

How can I find what is occupying my low memory on 32 bit Linux OS?

```
cat /proc/meminfo |grep Low
LowTotal:         812908 kB
LowFree:           43340 kB
```

Regards,

Comment: See http://wiki.openvz.org/UBC_systemwide_configuration#.E2.80.9CLow_memory.E2.80.9D_.28x86_32_specific.29 + http://wiki.openvz.org/Kmemsize#kmemsize

Comment: `free` will tell you. But it's also in all the other fields in `/proc/meminfo` that you ignored with your `grep`. Most likely, it's page cache.

Answer (score 1):

Low memory (aka ZONE_NORMAL) is all kernelspace. It will be for things like kernel modules, buffers for your network and storage devices, filesystems, and pagecache.

You can **cat /proc/slabinfo** to see detailed usage.